# DatePicker in MVC in IE gives me $ is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm trying to set up the jQuery datepicker for my MVC 5 app. When I pull the app up in Internet Explorer 11 I get the message ''$' is undefined'. You can see the rendered HTML with the offending line pointed out near the end of the post.

My model is set up like this:

```
namespace PublicationSystem.ViewModels
{
    public class ProfileEdit : IValidatableObject
    {
        public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        //...
    }
}
```

My edit View is like this:

```
@model PublicationSystem.ViewModels.ProfileEdit
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Profile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSmBanner.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
}
```

My layouts (they are nested):

_LayoutSmBanner.cshtml:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="main-column">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

_Layout.cshmtl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
        @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
        @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' defer></script>", "~/bundles/scripts")
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <footer class="footer">...</footer>
            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
                });
            </script>
</body>
```

The rendered HTML Head looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta ...>
        <title>...</title>

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <link href="/Content/css/bootstrap.3.3.5.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/css/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/resizable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/selectable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/accordion.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/button.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src='/Content/JS/jquery.1.11.2.js' defer></script>
        <script src='/Content/JS/bootstrap.3.3.4.js' defer></script>
        <script src='/Content/JS/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js' defer></script>
        <script src='/Content/JS/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js' defer>        </script>
        <script src='/Content/JS/Script.js' defer></script>

    </head>
```

And the body renders like this:

```
<body>
    ...
    <footer>...</footer>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {    // <--- IE errors here -----
                    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
                });
            </script>
</body>
```

Comment: because jQuery is not loaded. remove the `defer` on `script` tag

Comment: My PM says that is listed that way to 'allow it to load asynchronously with the defer tag'.

Comment: That is telling you that the reference to jQuery is not correct. Try adding the links to the script files manually to the head instead for using a script bundle...also make sure that jQuery is loaded before you call the function.

Comment: then wrap the last script tag  java script code inside a function and call it after jQuery gets loaded. But you are dependent on that jQuery file, so you may want to load the jQuery synchronously. Please advise your PM too. Load the files asynchronously which are not immediately required.

Comment: What are the files you are adding in 'scripts' bundle in bundleconfig.cs. Try with  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts") alone

Comment: I added the function to one of the scripts we load with the bundle. Now it works in IE.

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestions from the comments and other items I came up with this solution.

I added my datepicker script to \Content\JS\Script.js which is included when the script bundles load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy",
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

This enabled the script to run correctly after JQuery was loaded.

My Edit.cshtml ended up like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate)
    </div>
</div>
```

However, for that to work I needed to write a custom Date Editor, \Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Date.cshtml

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    var value = "";
    if (Model.HasValue) {
        value = String.Format("{0:d}", Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", value, new { @class = "datepicker", type = "text" })
```